# AppleScript: can I trigger the eyedropper tool upon opening the Mac colour picker?

Tags: applescript, color

I'd like to be able to use an eyedropper tool on command. The built-in Mac colour picker is nice, so to that end, I set up a keyboard shortcut using BetterTouchTool to open the colour picker; it does so simply by running the `choose color` AppleScript command.

This is only a partial solution, because I still need to click the eyedropper icon to get what I want. Apart from the minor nuisance of an extraneous click, the problem is that the click itself changes focus away from the application I'm using. (For example, suppose I'm using the eyedropper to test the `:focus` state of an element on a website.)

Is there a way to tell my script to run the eyedropper tool after opening the colour picker? In other words, I would like to automatically click the button indicated in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I download the trial of **BetterTouchTool** and resolved the issue in the following manner:

1. Added a **keyboard shortcut** assigning it: **⇧⌃P**
2. Added the built-in **Show Color Picker** *action* to the aforementioned *keyboard shortcut*.
3. Added a **Run AppleScript (async in background)** *action*, to the aforementioned *keyboard shortcut*, with the following **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        click (checkbox 1 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            window "Colors" of ¬
            application process "BetterTouchTool")
```

Note that this was done under **macOS Big Sur** and it works without issue after the initial setup and permissions setting as were prompted.

Now when I press **⇧⌃P** the **Color** *window* opens and the **color picker** *button* is clicked, and it is active to select a *color* where the mouse pointer was when the *keyboard shortcut* was pressed.

---

**Original Answer**

I do not have **BetterTouchTool**, so using **Script Editor** I find that if one just runs the `choose color` *command*, the **Colors** *window* is *modal* and does not allow any additional *code* that would click the **color picker** *button* to run.

To work around this, the `choose color` *command* can be wrapped within an `ignoring application responses` *statement*. However, while this allows the **color picker** *button* to be clicked by additional *code*, one does not get back, e.g. `{14896, 20151, 65429}` from the `choose color` *command* when the **OK** *button* is cliched after picking the color.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
ignoring application responses
    choose color
end ignoring

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click (checkbox 1 of ¬
        splitter group 1 of ¬
        window "Colors" of ¬
        application process "Script Editor")
```

---

This was tested under **macOS Catalina**.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I tried your code, but unfortunately I don't see a difference (i.e., I get the same result as just running `choose color`: the modal appears, but the eyedropper tool doesn't run automatically). I'm using Big Sur, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Théophile, I just copied and pasted the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ into **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** and it did indeed bring up the **Colors** _window_ and clicked the **color picker** _button_.  So it does work in that respect from **Script Editor**.  If you are copy and pasting the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in any other _application_ then `application process "Script Editor"` is of course not going to work as it did not call it.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Indeed, it works as you described from the Script Editor. Is there a way to change the last line to use the "current process" (I'm not sure what the right terminology is) or to search through all processes? The tool I use lets me assign keyboard shortcuts to commands, so I can hit `^+Shift+P` at any point to bring up the colour modal. So in short, is there a solution that doesn't involve opening the Script Editor?

Comment: @Théophile, There probably is a way, and I actually played around with it a bit, triggering it from **FastScripts**, but didn't get anywhere. I hope to look into it a bit more later but wanted you to know what I had found out so you could do some investigating on your own too.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I looked around some more and found a post that [seems promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292204/macosx-get-foremost-window-title). Based on that answer, I tried adding `set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true` at the beginning and then changed your last line to `application process whose id is frontApp`. It still doesn't work, but I feel that it must be close. This is my first time using AppleScript, though, so I'm at the limit of my knowledge here...

Comment: @Théophile, Please see the updated answer for a resolution to your issue. Thanks.

Comment: That's it! Amazing! I had forgotten that BetterTouchTool can do everything. :) Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this will help you, but if all you are looking to do is retrieve the color values at your exact mouse coordinates, this alternate solution may be an option for you.

This following AppleScript code added as an AppleScript action to a new Automator Quick Action, will allow you to retrieve color values at your exact mouse coordinates, without the need to call on System Events or any Color Picker GUI.

[image]

I saved my version in Automator as “Eyedropper At Mouse Location.workflow”.  I then assigned it the keyboard shortcut **⇧⌃P** in **System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Services**. Now, pressing the keyboard shortcut **⇧⌃P** while in any application, will retrieve the RGB color values at my exact mouse location.

**—————————————————————————————————————-**

This code requires the third-party utility, [**Cliclick**](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/).

> “Cliclick” is short for “**C**ommand-**L**ine **I**nterface **Click**”. It is a a tiny shell/Terminal application that will emulate mouse clicks or series of mouse clicks (including doubleclicks and control-clicks) at arbitrary screen coordinates. Moreover, it lets you move the mouse, get the current mouse coordinates, press modifier keys etc.

It's free to download but it's [donationware](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/donations/), and is easy to install.

On my system I have. `cliclick` in the following directory: `/usr/local/bin/`. Because of this location, in my AppleScript code and in Terminal app, I need to use the full path to `cliclick` to call the command. For example: `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick rc:."` In AppleScript is telling `cliclick` to right-click.

**—————————————————————————————————————-**

I’m not quite sure what you intend to do with the color values retrieved so I created three different variables… `rgbColors` (R,G,B values as integers as record), `theColors` (R,G,B values as text as list), and `theColorsAsText` (R,G,B values as 1 long string)

```
property rgbColors : {R:0, G:0, B:0}

set theColors to words of ¬
    ((do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick cp:.") as string) as list

set theColorsAsText to (("Red:" & theColors's item 1) & "  Green:" & ¬
    theColors's item 2) & "  Blue:" & theColors's item 3

(* Not Necessary But This Will Store The Values As A Record Making It ¬
Easier To Call On Or Manipulate, If Need Be, In Other Parts Of The Script*)
set {rgbColors's R, rgbColors's G, rgbColors's B} to ¬
    {theColors's item 1 as integer, theColors's item 2 as integer, ¬
        theColors's item 3 as integer}

activate
display dialog theColorsAsText buttons {"OK"} ¬
    default button "OK" giving up after 4
```